# Unusable Source for Ubuntu image on Xen 3

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, xen, opensuse

I'm trying to create a new VM in Xen 3, running Ubuntu 10.4 (32 bit) as the guest OS.

Xen 3 is installed on a machine running OpenSuse 11.2.

I downloaded the Ubuntu image from the ubuntu.com website and I mounted it on /dev/loop0.

When I try to create the new VM in Xen with the given source, Xen complains the "source is unusable".

I've also checked the md5 sum for the image. It's fine.

Any suggestion or hint that could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ISO file as a "Virtual Hard Disk" with read-only rather than a "Virtual CD/DVD" seemed to help.